# Return from function

Tags: powershell, return

I wish to return from the following powershell function if I find a match (for a more complete code sample see my [codereview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13816/9313)):

```
Function Find-Property($fileName, $PropertyName)
{
    $shellfolder = Create-ShellFolder $fileName
    0..287 | Foreach-Object {
        if($PropertyName -eq $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)){ return $_ }
    }
}
```

This code just appears to return from the scope of the if conditional, which is not so useful.

How can I do this? Do I need a labeled break somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use the `return` statement to exit the function you can use the `foreach` keyword  instead of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. Here's a demo:

```
function Foo {
    foreach ($number in (0..287)) {
        $number # Just show our current iteration.
        if ($number -eq 50) {
            return $number
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for a label.

```
function Find-Property($Filename, $PropertyName)
{
    $shellfolder = Create-ShellFolder $fileName
    0..287 | Where {$PropertyName -eq $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)} | 
             Foreach {$_;break}
}
```

Another option is to minorly tweak your original function:

```
function Find-Property($fileName, $PropertyName)
{
    $shellfolder = Create-ShellFolder $fileName
    0..287 | Foreach-Object {
        if($PropertyName -eq $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)) {$_; break}
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to generically break out of a function? (I imagine that having a `C` style return would be much more efficient. Additionally, I don't that that the code you provided has any performance boost (in fact, the `Where` cmdlet might make it slower

Comment: Yes, `return` normally allows you to alter control flow and exit immmediately from a function (optionally returning a value).  However, the behavior of return inside a pipeline is different. It exits the current scriptblock.  Generally, I avoid using `return` inside a pipeline.

Comment: @soandos in your question, you don't mention anything about performance concerns.  :-)

Comment: The concept works: 
`PS> function foo { 0..287 | %{if ($_ -eq 5) {$_; break}} }
PS> foo # outputs 5`